# Not able to access the keywords in .robot file in one directory from other directory after creating python package

Tags: python, testing, automation, robotframework

Not able to access the keywords in .robot file in one directory from other directory after creating python package. Although I am able to access methods of .py but not .robot file.

I have created Python package(which contains .robot test suite) so that I can reuse the keywords in that particular package in any other project by simply importing the Library anywhere
I have successfully created and installed package(named as Resources which contains some .robot test suites and .py files). Now I want to use the keywords from 'Resources' package in some other Robot project. Here, problem is when I write below statement:
**Library Resources**
I am not able to use the keyword given in Resources package. But If I import that particular robot file, them I am able to access the keyword: e.g
**Resource ../../../../Documents/MyWorkspace/RobotFramework/Resources/PostLoginSearch.robot**
Here I do not want to import using above absolute path since it can be done without creating package also. So is it possible to use keywords by only importing Resources package.
Also I have successfully created and installed "Resources" package and I could see the version also. I am able to call the python methods but unable to access the keyword in Resources .robot file after importing "Resources" package

And this "Resources" is in some other project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKQhy.png)

Answer (score 0):

[creating test libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries)

**Library search path**

The most common way to specify a test library to import is using its name. The Robot Framework tries to find the class or module implementing the library from the library search path. Basically, this means that the library code and all its possible dependencies must be in PYTHONPATH. If your library is in PYTHONPATH environment variable then use

```
Library <<name of your custom library>>
```

**Updated after introspection**

i do not think, this is allowed in robot, since, by definition , when one creates python user-defined library, it would be containing only .py files, since, they are custom-library.

On the other hand, resource files provide a mechanism to User keywords and variables created in the robot which contains .robot extension.

These are 2 different aspects, I feel that you are combining 2 different things which should not be.

Maybe an alternative approach is to define all the common keywords(not custom *.py) files as part of the testsuite itself, so that, when any test case(s)/ modules are calling they would get inherited at once.

**Better Approach**

1. Group all your common keywords into one file(s), make it available for all the testcases to consume i.e **using Resource under settings section.**
2. Create Custom-test Library and put it under PYTHONPATH and access those methods as keywords as well.

Comment: In Library we can only import python files. But here my package contains non .py files i.e. .robot files. So that's why I am not able to use the keywords given in Resources/PostLoginSearch.robot file since it is like a folder and not python file. So if I need to use these robot file in external project I need to create a package that is already successfully installed. But I am not understanding the way to use keywords in those robot files in external projects.

Comment: Also I have added an image showing the folder structure for reference. Please check the image

Comment: i do not think, this is allowed in robot, since, by definition , when one creates python user-defined library, it would be containing only .py files, since, they are custom-library. On the other hand, resource files provide a mechanism to User keywords and variables created in robot which contains .robot extension.
these are 2 different aspects, i feel that you are combining 2 different things which should not be.

Comment: maybe an alternative approach is to define all the common keywords(not custom *.py) files as part of the testsuite itself , so that , when any testcase(s)/ modules are calling they would get inherited at once.

Comment: I want to explore the option of packaging our automation as tools(e.g. robot files containing keywords, locators, python files) and tests(automation test suite) so that we can reuse the automation done by other teams.
I should be able to do pip install of the package that contains the keywords of that application. I should package our tools module and install inside tests module with pip install and run the same

Comment: Do you any way to achieve the above mentioned scenario